# How to avoid plotting lines through discontinuities (vertical asymptotes)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a code for `ctg(x)` but I don't want asymptotes or I want that they have a different color. I'm a beginner and I don't know what I can change in this code:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as tck
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
x=np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi,100)
y=np.cos(x)/np.sin(x)
plt.ylim([-4, 4])
ax.plot(x/np.pi,y)
plt.title("f(x) = ctg(x)")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tck.FormatStrFormatter('%g $\pi$'))
plt.savefig('ctg')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you post the current plot result (image) and the expected plot (draw it using other tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an asymptote being draw, but the line for the points around zero.
To overcome this you should create two plots for the positive and negative parts separately, making sure that the color (style?) for the two plots is the same (and optionally get the first default matplotlib color).
Since `np.linspace()` includes the extrema, these might accidentally create the same artifact.
To overcome this, it is enough to add/subtract a small number (`epsilon`) to the extrema.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))

# get first default color
color = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'][0]

epsilon = 1e-7
intervals = (
    (-np.pi, 0),
    (0, np.pi), )
for a, b in intervals:
    x=np.linspace(a + epsilon, b - epsilon, 50)
    y=np.cos(x) / np.sin(x)
    ax.plot(x/np.pi,y, color=color)

plt.title("f(x) = ctg(x)")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.ylim([-4, 4])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%g $\pi$'))
plt.savefig('ctg')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I try to draw tg(x) but when I change the positive and negative part it don't works :`x=np.linspace(-np.pi, -(1/2)*np.pi, 50)
y=np.sin(x)/np.cos(x)
ax.plot(x/np.pi,y, color=color)

x=np.linspace(-(1/2)*np.pi, (1/2)*np.pi, 50)
y=np.sin(x)/np.cos(x)
ax.plot(x/np.pi,y, color=color)

x=np.linspace((1/2)*np.pi, np.pi, 50)
y=np.sin(x)/np.cos(x)
ax.plot(x/np.pi,y, color=color)
`

Comment: That is because the asymptotes of `tan(x)` are in different place. You need to have the plots separated at the discontinuities of the function you would like to plot. In the case of `cot(x)` is at `x == 0` but could be anywhere. You may need to use `endpoint=False` when defining `x` with `np.linspace()`.

Comment: I change the ranges when tg(x) have asymptotes but it still don't works :/

Comment: @wvnikax You shall avoid including the extrema. You can do so by including a small epsilon.. see edits.

Answer (score 0):

[image]This code creates a figure and one subplot for cotangent function. NaN are inserted when sin(x) is tending to 0 (NaN means "Not a Number" and NaNs are not plotted or connected).
matplot-fmt-pi created by k-donn(https://pypi.org/project/matplot-fmt-pi/) used to change the formatter to make x labels and ticks correspond to multiples of π/8 in fractional format.
plot formatting (grid, legend, limits, axis) is performed as commented.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplot_fmt_pi import MultiplePi

fig, ax = plt.subplots()        # creates a figure and one subplot
x = np.linspace(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
y = 1/np.tan(x)
y[np.abs(np.sin(x)) <= np.abs(np.sin(x[1]-x[0]))] = np.nan
# This operation inserts a NaN where sin(x) is reaching 0
# NaN means "Not a Number" and NaNs are not plotted or connected
ax.plot(x, y, lw=2, color="blue", label='Cotangent')
# Set up grid, legend, and limits
ax.grid(True)
ax.axhline(0, color='black', lw=.75)
ax.axvline(0, color='black', lw=.75)
ax.set_title("Trigonometric Functions")
ax.legend(frameon=False)    # remove frame legend frame
# axis formatting
ax.set_xlim(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi)
pi_manager = MultiplePi(8)          # number= ticks between 0 - pi
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(pi_manager.locator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(pi_manager.formatter())
plt.ylim(top=10)  # y axis limit values
plt.ylim(bottom=-10)
y_ticks = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
plt.yticks(y_ticks)
fig
plt.show()
```